# YouTube API v3 language filter

Tags: api, youtube-api

Is there any option to filter the results by language in YouTube v3 search API?
In v2 there is parameter like lr which i can set to specified language.

Answer (score 0):

There is no language filtering in Youtube API v3. The only thing you can make with Youtube API v3 is you can use the [region code](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#regionCode) such that

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=is&regionCode=YOUR_REGION_CODE&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

However, it most probably will not do what you want. Therefore, you should use some external language filtering libraries

Comment: The hl parameter specifies the language that should be used for text values in the API response. The default value is en_US.

Answer (score 0):

**relevanceLanguage string**

> The relevanceLanguage parameter instructs the API to return search
>   results that are most relevant to the specified language. The
>   parameter value is typically an ISO 639-1 two-letter language code.
>   However, you should use the values zh-Hans for simplified Chinese and
>   zh-Hant for traditional Chinese. Please note that results in other
>   languages will still be returned if they are highly relevant to the
>   search query term.

see also [YouTube Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list)

Comment: it doesn't filter the results. It just relies on the sorting a bit.